# Better use EM.next_tick or EM.defer for long running calculation with Eventmachine?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, eventmachine, asynchronous

I am trying to figure out how to make use of deferrables when it comes to long running computations that I have to implement on my own. For my example I want to calculate the first 200000 Fibonacci numbers but return only a certain one.

My first attempt of a deferrable looked like so:

```
class FibA
  include EM::Deferrable

  def calc m, n
    fibs = [0,1]
    i = 0

    do_work = proc{
      puts "Deferred Thread: #{Thread.current}"
      if i < m
        fibs.push(fibs[-1] + fibs[-2])
        i += 1
        EM.next_tick &do_work
      else
        self.succeed fibs[n]
      end
    }
    EM.next_tick &do_work
  end
end

EM.run do
  puts "Main Thread: #{Thread.current}"
  puts "#{Time.now.to_i}\n"

  EM.add_periodic_timer(1) do
    puts "#{Time.now.to_i}\n"
  end

  # calculating in reactor thread
  fib_a = FibA.new
  fib_a.callback do |x|
    puts "A - Result: #{x}"
    EM.stop
  end
  fib_a.calc(150000, 21)
end
```

Only to realize that everything seemed to work pretty well, but the thread the deferrable runs in is the same as the reactor thread (knowing that everything runs inside one system thread unless rbx or jruby are used). So I came up with a second attempt that seems nicer to me, especially because of different callback binding mechanism and the use of different threads.

```
class FibB
  include EM::Deferrable

  def initialize
    @callbacks = []
  end

  def calc m, n
    work = Proc.new do
      puts "Deferred Thread: #{Thread.current}"
      @fibs = 1.upto(m).inject([0,1]){ |a, v| a.push(a[-1]+a[-2]); a }
    end

    done = Proc.new do
      @callbacks.each{ |cb| cb.call @fibs[n]}
    end

    EM.defer work, done
  end

  def on_done &cb
    @callbacks << cb
  end
end

EM.run do
  puts "Main Thread: #{Thread.current}"
  puts "#{Time.now.to_i}\n"

  EM.add_periodic_timer(1) do
    puts "#{Time.now.to_i}\n"
  end

  # calculating in external thread
  fib_b = FibB.new
  fib_b.on_done do |res|
    puts "B - Result: #{res}"
  end
  fib_b.on_done do
    EM.stop
  end
  fib_b.calc(150000, 22)
end
```

Which one is the implementation that I should prefer? Are both wrong? Is there another, a better one?

Even more interesting: Is the second attempts a perfect way to implement whatever I want (except I/O op's) without blocking the reactor?

Comment: Why do you need EventLoop for computations? EM is a good choice for non-blocking network IO, but here is no any need for it

Comment: My final app does heavy IO with Redis, MongoDB, a WebSocket server, disc and several HTTP endpoints using appripiate em-libraries. Unfortunately during shuffling data between these I have to make some CPU/memory intense calculations, and I am looking for a way to realize these without blocking a single reactor tick. But anyhow, thank you for your comment.

Comment: `defer` will block your app but only for 10ms max each time thread scheduler will unlock it. `defer` is a good choice for blocking IO (syscalls ie), because they release GIL, but your calculations won't. `next_tick` implementation shouldn't block for a long time at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely EM.defer (or Thread.new I suppose), doing a long-running calculation in EM.next_tick will block your reactor for other things.

As a general rule, you don't want ANY block running inside reactor to be running for long regardless if it is or isn't IO blocking or the entire app halts while this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, also, if you're still in an early phase of your project, consider switching to celluloid::io as eventmachine isn't actively developed for 2 years now it seems and any trouble you'll have with it, you'll be on your own (this goes especially if you mean to use jruby as eventmachine+jruby is pretty much in beta)

Comment: Is celluloid evented?

Comment: @Donato, Celluloid is an actor library, akin to Akka to some degree, it has a hybrid actor+evented offshoot called Celluloid IO - https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-io. Celluloid alone is typically enough, but these days I use Concurrent Ruby, https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby, some design choices in Celluloid were hard to live with so I'm trying the other thing

Comment: To be honest, evented is overrated, especially when the rest of the ecosystem doesn't support it, you end up throwing everything into `EM.defer` block equivalents anyway - if that's the story you might as well use actors/futures/etc instead.

Comment: I was planning on using sidekiq to create an imap client that polled activerecord users. These I/O operations can cause significant blocking. Consequently, the author of sidekiq recommended me to use EventMachine instead (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459985/stop-sidekiq-worker-when-user-logs-out). Now I have been reading your posts. And you do not recommend eventmachine. You still recommend Concurrent Ruby for my need? I already have invested several days with eventmachine.

Comment: A lot of good software was written with EM, my pains don't mean that you can't make a simple component which will do one thing and do it well and no worries. However, if your job will tend to grow, implement more and more business logic etc, I would think of other solutions, one option is to use EM, or Node, or anything really, including concurrent-ruby to build a super simple communication component that goes through imap on one end and sends HTTP requests to another service which handles the business logic.

Comment: Building complex stuff with EM is a bitch, I later found out that building complex stuff is bitchy with Celluloid too, now I'm fiddling with concurrent-ruby, bottom line, that stuff is complex and tricky and should be extracted and complex aspects of the job delegated. If you can