# Architecture advice for EventMachine and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, eventmachine

We are writing a real-time game in EventMachine/Ruby. We're using ActiveRecord with MySQL for storing the game objects.

When we start the server we plan to load all the game objects into memory. This will allow for us to avoid any blocking/slow SQL queries with ActiveRecord.

However, we still need to persist the data in the database in case the server crashes, of course.

What are our options for doing so? I could use `EM.Defer` but I have no idea how many concurrent players that could handle since the thread pool is limited to 20.

Currently I'm thinking using Resque with Redis would be the best bet. Do everything with the objects in memory, and whenever there is a save that needs to occur for the database, fire off a job and add it to the Resque queue.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

1. Threadpool size can be tweaked - see `EventMachine.threadpool_size`
2. Each server process (apache...) will spawn its own EventMachine reactor and its own `EM.defer` threadpool, so if you use a forking server (a mongrel farm, passenger, ...) you don't need to go crazy on the threadpool size
3. See EM-Synchrony by Ilja Grigorik (https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) - you should be able to simplify your code with it
4. Afaik, mysql has a non-blocking driver that you can use freely with EM, EM::Synchrony supports it http://www.igvita.com/2010/04/15/non-blocking-activerecord-rails/ - this would mean you don't need EM.defer at all!
5. Take a look at Thin - https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/ - it's non-blocking EM-based webserver that supports Rails

**Having said all this, writing evented code is a bitch** - forget about stack traces and make sure you're running benchmark tests often as anything blocking your reactor will block the entire application.

Also, this all applies to MRI Ruby ONLY. If you mean to use jruby... You're bound to get into trouble as thread-safety of eventmachine seems to be largely due to GIL of MRI Ruby and standard patterns don't work (many aspects of it can be made to work with this fork https://github.com/WebtehHR/eventmachine/tree/v1.0.3_w_fix which fixes some issues EM has with JRuby)

Unfortunately, guys from https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine are kind of not very active, the project currently has 200+ issues and almost 60 open pull requests which is why I've had to use a separate fork to continue playing with my current project - this still means EM is an awesome project just don't expect problems you encounter to be quickly fixed so do your best to not go out of the trodden path of EM use.

Another problem with JRuby is that EM::Synchrony imposes a heavy performance penalty because JRuby doesn't have implemented fibers as of 1.7.8 but rather maps them to Java native threads which are MUCH slower

---

Also, have you considered messaging with something like RabbitMQ (it has a synchronous https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny, and evented driver https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp) as a possibility to communicate game objects between clients and perhaps reduce overhead on the database / distributed memory store that you had in mind?

Redis/Resque seem good, but if all the jobs will need to do is simple persistance, and if there will be A LOT of such calls, you might want to consider beanstalkd - it has A LOT faster but simpler queue then Resque and you can probably make this even faster if you don't really need activerecord to dump attribute hashes into the database, see [delayed_jobs vs resque vs beanstalkd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808351/delayed-jobs-vs-resque-vs-beanstalkd)

Answer (score 1):

A couple years and a failed project later, some thoughts:

avoid eventmachine if any way possible, there's a plethora of opportunities to peg your CPU nowadays with YARV/MRI Ruby on a IO constrained application and without wasting memory.

My favorite approach for a web application at this time is use Puma with multiple processes and threads.

Have in mind that GIL in YARV only affects the Ruby interpreter code, not the IO operations, meaning that on a IO constrained application you can add threads and see better utilization of a single core,

add more processes and you see better utilization of many cores :) On Heroku 1x worker we run 2 processes with 4 threads each and this pegs our CPU potential to the top in benchmark meaning the application is no longer IO bound, but CPU bound and doing so without unacceptable memory losses.

When we needed super-fast responses we were troubled by the DB write operation times which did not affect the response to client, so we did asynchronous database writes using `sidekiq` / `resque`,

In hindsight you could even do `celluloid` or `concurrent-ruby` for asynchronous IO reads/writes (think DB writes, cache visits etc), it's less overhead and infrastructure but harder to debug and problem solve in production - my worst nightmare being an async operation failing silently with no error trace in our `Errors` console (an exception in exception handling for example)

**End result** is that your application experiences the same sort of benefits you used to get from using eventmachine (elimination of the IO bound, full utilization of CPU without huge memory footprint, parallel non-blocking IO) without resorting to writing reactor code which is a complete bitch to do as explained in my 2013 post

Comment: I am planning to build an imap client which polls the email servers of activerecord users. The author of sidekiq told me sidekiq is not designed for this; that I should use eventmachine. And now you are saying to stay away from eventmachine. Not sure which direction I should go.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074518/better-use-em-next-tick-or-em-defer-for-long-running-calculation-with-eventmachi/20419767?noredirect=1#comment66383225_20419767